# Python 3.4 - List index out of range error occurs when running script, but not in interpreter

Tags: python, list, pycharm

Consider the following list, that I call `innerlist` with the values:

`['66957039892995', '-70', '-70', '-70', '1', '1', '0', '']`

I am trying to make a dictionary using the list above. It works fine when I do it manually in the Python interpreter.

```
datadict = {         
              'a': innerlist[0],         
              'b': innerlist[1],         
              'c': innerlist[2],         
              'd': innerlist[3],
              'e': innerlist[4],
              'f': innerlist[5],
              'g': innerlist[6],
              'h': "not available" if not innerlist[7] else innerlist[7]     
           }
```

In the interpreter, it makes the dictionary without any errors. and when I find out the length of the list it outputs 8.

However, when I try to run this code within a script, Pycharm throws the following error:

```
File "**hidden filepath**", line 25, in make_wd
    'h': "not available" if not innerlist[7] else innerlist[7]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**EDIT**: The script:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

def make_wd(innerlist):
    datadict = {
        'a': innerlist[0],
        'b': innerlist[1],
        'c': innerlist[2],
        'd': innerlist[3],
        'e': innerlist[4],
        'f': innerlist[5],
        'g': innerlist[6],
        'h': "not available" if not innerlist[7] else innerlist[7]
    }
    return datadict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        client = MongoClient()
    except :
        print("Could not connect to MongoDB")
    db = client.testdb
    innerlist = ['66957039892995', '-70', '-70', '-70', '1', '1', '0', '']
    testdict = make_wd(innerlist)
    db.testcollection.insert_one(testdict)
```

Comment: I think the list in your script is missing one of those duplicated values. Oversight?

Comment: The code you posted works fine both in the interpreter and in a script. So the code in the script must be different to raise the error.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, it's the same list that I pass to the function in the script.

Comment: please post the full content of the script, so we can identify the error

Comment: Your code Just works fine on both interpreter and script.

Comment: What would be a good way to check for an empty list element? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: You seem to be storing numbers as strings and using an empty string to represent 'no number'. If you are really only storing numbers then a better way might be to just store them as numbers (removing the `'`s) and using `None` to indicate 'no number'. The way you check it would need to be changed to `if not innerlist[7] == None`, because `not innerlist[7]` would be true for the number `0`. Note though that it might also be better to simply store `None` in the dictionary rather than `"not available"`.

Comment: @Marein, the 'h' element is a string

Comment: Following up on my latest point, you can more easily create the final dictionary using `dict(zip('abcdefgh', innerlist))`. But only if you accept the value from `innerlist` without changing it.

Comment: @omrakhur: Do you mean the `'h'` element can be any string? What does it represent? If the list is not homogeneously typed and always the same length, you probably want to use a tuple instead. If you want to use key/value relations like in a dictionary for your non-homogeneous, fixed length data, I would suggest a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). It's hard to tell what is best without knowing more about the purpose of this code.

Comment: Also this is going quite far away from the original question, which just involved an error, so perhaps consider opening a new question.

Comment: @Marein: I'm making a dictionary to be later inserted into MongoDB. This is a test script for a new type of data. All the elements except for the 'h' element are numbers, but the 'h' element is meant to store a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149699/discussion-between-marein-and-omrakhur).

Comment: The Mongo stuff is all irrelevant to your question. Please remove code that isn't needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 you're right. But I pasted it because several comments above asked for it

Comment: @omrakhur You misunderstand. Don't remove the entire script. Just remove the parts that aren't required to demonstrate the problem. In other words, apply the "minimal" in [mcve].

Comment: Like @Rahul, your script works as expected (no error) on my machine as well. Have you tried running it outside of PyCharm? You may have some strange configuration going on.

Comment: @jpmc26, yes I ran it on the interpreter within terminal and that was working fine.

Comment: @omrakhur So you ran the script with a command like `python myscripp.py`, and it worked? Check exactly what script PyCharm is running. It may not be running the one you think it is.

Comment: I did that, and according to the trace, it is running the intended script. For the moment, I have used a try-except block as a workaround

Answer (score -1):

Use ipdb to put breakpoint and check what is really there in the list while running script

You can do it by install `pip install ipdb`

and try to put breakpoint before dict creation

```
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
```

For a condition when you will not have 7th index, you should try with

```
if len(your_list)>7 and your_list[7]:
    data = your_list[7]
else:
    data = "Not Available"
```

And use data to assign "h"

Comment: @Benjie Then great. He can use to debug